# RestAPi with RestSharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, restsharp, azure-devops-rest-api

I'have a simple restApi, when I call it with postMan it works but in asp.net by restsharp it return always nothing.

Why?

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://testapiall1.azurewebsites.net/myapi/test/1")

client.Timeout = -1
Dim requestapi = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
   
requestapi.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

Dim responseapi As IRestResponse = client.Execute(requestapi)

Dim j As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(responseapi.Content)
```

Recap: If I call Rest API with https not working.

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://testapiall1.azurewebsites.net/myapi/test/1")
```

Only Http works

```
Dim client = New RestClient("http://testapiall1.azurewebsites.net/myapi/test/1")
```

The RestApi is on the MS Azure everybody can access, please someone can write some code for .Net that works?

Comment: RestSharp can deserialize the JSON for you. Why are you doing it yourself? Did you look at any of the documentation?

Comment: ->MY problem is that  responseapi.Content IS EMPTY

Comment: If you test this link https://testapiall1.azurewebsites.net/myapi/test/1, it works, whats wrong in my code?

Comment: How do you know that the response is empty? Why are you deserializing to an Object instead of some useful type?

Comment: If I execute Http instead Https it works! but repeat the problem is only with code in RestSharp.

Comment: You haven't answered my questions.

Comment: I need to parse as Object in var J. Anyway last row of code I can change, my problem is that responseapi.Content is empty. The call to RestApi it seems blocked, instead if I change url in "http://testapiall1.azurewebsites.net/myapi/test/1" it works.

Comment: Did you [check the documentation](https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#response)? Check the other properties of the IRestResponse?

Comment: Yes i see and I added that code client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf customCertValidation), but nothing change.

Comment: Is Alexey Zimarev's answer helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please mark it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your "API" doesn't return a valid JSON. It returns a string "value", which is *not* JSON.

Second, you try to deserialize to type `object`, which is not something you can do. You *must* deserialize to a specific type.

With RestSharp 107 you can do:

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://testapiall1.azurewebsites.net/myapi/test/1")
Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.Get)
Dim response = Await client.ExecuteAsync(requestapi)
```

The `response.Content` will then be `value`.